# How do you get the document id after adding document in Cloud Firestore in Dart after the new update

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am using the following code to update a Cloud Firestore collection using Dart/Flutter.

```
 final _url =  FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('builders')
            .doc('builder id')
            .collection('projects')
            .doc();

await _url.set({'docId': _url.documentID});
```

This used to work earlier but now it show a error message:

**The getter 'documentId' isn't defined for the type 'DocumentReference'.**

Can someone please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"documentId" is now "id"

Comment: thank you Moo it was a silly thing but i got it. 
Regards